# How to pop to root view controller on custom tab bar button clicked iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am showing custom tab bar using tab bar controller.

And Creating Separate navigationController for view controllers.

```
First *firstViewController = [[First alloc]init];
UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

Second *secondViewController = [[Second alloc]init];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

Third *thirdViewController = [[Third alloc]init];
UINavigationController *thirdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];

tabBar.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, nil];
tabBar.delegate=self;
tabBar.selectedIndex=0;
```

but when i am trying to pop to root on tab click, Only 3rd navigation controller is accessible.

So its working for only 3rd tab, First and second is not working.

Comment: What are you doing in tabar delegate. Please add it into your post.

Comment: I don't really know, what you are up to, but if you want all those view-controllers to be popped on a single button click, you'll probably have to iterate though all those Viewcontrollers, you have registered in your tab bar object.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `tabBar.viewControllers = @[firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController];`

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading a view controller on top of a `tabBarController` this is how you would dismiss your loaded view controller.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:self completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationController * navController = (UINavigationController *) [[[tabbarcontroller viewControllers] objectAtIndex: tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex] rootViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all those viewcontrollers to be popped, you may find this delegate useful.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

//iterate though tabbar-viewcontrollers to pop all of them

//return NO, if you want this to be handled like an action
return NO;

//return YES, if you want this to be handled like a normal selection
return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
It will pop to rootViewController when tap on the tab.

-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```